# Handle NA in R when calling as.numeric

Tags: r, replace, format, numeric, na

I have a vector with the following format:

```
> test <- c("3", "5", "?", "7")
> test <- as.numeric(test)
> test
[1] 3 5 NA 7
```

Is it possible to specify what happens to missing values when calling **as.numeric**? I would like to use the mean, median, or any other suitable calculation of the other values instead.

Comment: Not from within `as.numeric` afaik, but you can easily replace `NA` entries afterwards

Comment: You could write a method (with `as.double`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are requesting is hardly possible. If you want to replace the value by the mean value, you have to read all values first.
However, you can fix it afterwards:

```
test[is.na(test)] <- mean(test, na.rm=TRUE)
```